# Are employers who got their PPP loan on a later date better off than those who got it early?

Tags: united-states, small-business, california, covid-19, unemployment

My understanding is that

1. payroll expenses that would be eligible for PPP loan forgiveness must be incurred immediately within the next 8 weeks when PPP funds appeared in the employer's bank account. Basically employer can't decide at their own discretion when they start to use PPP funds. AND
2. employees can't receive both unemployment benefits and salary (also when salary is subsidized with PPP funds) at the same time.

**So, isn't the winning strategy to postpone usage of PPP money for eligible payroll expenses when businesses are actually open and employees are not eligible for regular unemployment benefits that are paid by state anyway?**

Answer (score 1):

After talking with few CPAs, yes, the optimal strategy is to postpone usage of PPP loan until business can reopen. PPP flexibility act singed on June 5th solves this by allowing borrowers to spend PPP money over 24 weeks instead of 8 weeks.